# Make nav vertical align fixed on middle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, css-position, nav

I wanted to make a nav vertical fixed on right and its show in all devices on middle. I create a simple but its not working perfectly. how can i make nav fixed on middle in all devices. now its not work on small screen.

```
<header class="header" id="nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="main-menu">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#home">
            <h2>Home</h2> <i class="fa fa-circle"> </i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="#about">
            <h2>About</h2> <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</header>
```

Here is link [nav](http://codepen.io/sifulbd/full/zqvaEO/.)
Thanks in Advance

Comment: so what's your question exactly?

Comment: I want nav on middle in all devices.

Comment: You can try `transform-origin: 50% -50%;`. But align becomes a hard work after a 2d/3d transform. You can flip your buttons at the photoshop and place them on your website in the regular way.

Comment: Plus, you did use `margin-bottom: 100px` to keep your buttons away one of each other, its not going to fit good on any mobile device.

Comment: [**take a look on this pen -click-**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNvamj?editors=1100) i did flip the entire list instead of each item on separated, to remove the `margin-bottom: 100px`

Comment: but its still not working as i want. Its not working on small height device.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code on parent div:

```
 .vertical-middle {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

set the width of the nav in percentage to keep it responsive in different screen sizes and then use margin:auto to center it.

Comment: this is not problem with width. its about height.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical centering is a huge pain in my experience. There are tons of answers all over stackoverflow to help you get the css just right to get it.

Personally I have found [How To Center In CSS](http://howtocenterincss.com/) a great code generator that handles my trouble almost all the time. This should at least help get you vertically aligned so you can do your other styling more easily.